# How to use user-scoped credentials in an AWS credentials parameter in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to access AWS credentials provided via a parameter in my pipeline job.

I have a pipeline job where I am using an AWS credentials parameter defined like this:

```
credentials (
    credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl', 
    defaultValue: 'jenkins-deploy-proj', 
    description: '''
    My description
    ''', 
    name: 'AWS_ACCOUNT'
)
```

I got that via "Pipeline Syntax > Declarative Directive Generator > Parameters" in the Jenkins UI.

I need to access those credentials later in the in the job. [From other discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736638/define-credential-parameter-in-parameters-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) it seems to be that I should use a `withCredentials` block to access the credentials , so I tried this

```
script {
    withCredentials([[
        $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 
        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
        credentialsId: "${params.AWS_ACCOUNT}"
    ]]) {
        sh 'bash myscript.sh'
    }
}
```

I got that via "Pipeline Syntax > Snippet Generator > withCredentials" in the Jenkins UI.

The pipeline runs fine with the default credentials (which are accessible to all users) but when I attempt to use my personal credentials (still in the global domain) I get an error from Jenkins telling me that the credentials don't exist:

`ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID '557ff283-70f3-402b-b065-fb4c9f28305e'`

I can use those same credentials as a parameter in other (non-pipeline) Jenkins jobs configured like this, and they work fine:

[image: parameter definition]
[image: parameter binding]

I did make take an extra step to make sure the problem wasn't just with that one credential object by creating a new credential object, but I got the same `Could not find credentials entry with ID` error.

Comment: It sounds as if your credentials have not been added to the list in the credentials plugin settings for AWS.

Comment: Is that setting specific to pipeline jobs? I'll check on that, but it seems strange that non-pipeline jobs would not require that setting, while pipeline jobs do.

Comment: Pipelines can also use plain text credentials, but that has security implications.

Comment: True. The reason I'm using user-scoped credentials here is because we want to lock down who can run a job in a given environment based on whether they can provide the necessary credentials. So a shared set of credentials (or plaintext credentials) doesn't help too much. Also the "shared credentials" scenario already works without modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reach out to [CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) support (they provide tools and services on top of Jenkins) who mentioned a change introduced in [JENKINS-58170](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58170) which allows credentials to be accessed using the name of the credentials parameter as the id. This is the solution mentioned in [this CloudBees article about using user scoped credentials in pipeline jobs](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/user-scoped-creds). In this case the solution would have looked like:

```
script {
    withCredentials([[
        $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 
        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
        credentialsId: 'AWS_ACCOUNT'
    ]]) {
        sh 'bash myscript.sh'
    }
}
```

This will likely work for many Jenkins users.

These improvements, however, came in with version 2.3 of [the credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/). Since we were running an older version of the plugin, this capability was not available.

Instead, we had to use the "special syntax" mentioned on [JENKINS-58170](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58170): `credentialsId: '${credentialsParameterName}'`. Note that the single quotes are important here! From the ticket:

> user-scoped credentials are currently only looked up if the credential id is provided using the former template syntax

That is, the `'{userScopedCredsParameterName}'` syntax.

So final working pipeline definition looked like this:

```
script {
    withCredentials([[
        $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 
        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
        credentialsId: '${AWS_ACCOUNT}'
    ]]) {
        sh 'bash myscript.sh'
    }
}
```