# Jenkins and Privately Scoped Credentials on a Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have been trying to get Jenkins user-scoped credentials to work on a pipeline last few days. In the end, I've boiled it down to this:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        credentials(name: 'creds_param', credentialType: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl', required: true)
    ])
])

stage('example'){
    node {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '${creds_param}', variable: 'SECRET')]) {
            sh 'echo $SECRET'
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but before the pipeline runs, it requires "List User Credentials" checkbox to be checked and the secret selected from the drop-down menu. Unfortunately, even just adding the `defaultValue` property (to avoid having to actually select a secret from the drop-down after checking the checkbox) causes the secret lookup to fail, like so:

```
        ...
        credentials(
            name: 'creds_param',
            defaultValue: 'salainen2',
            credentialType: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl',
            required: true
        )
        ...
```

Is there a way to avoid the user interaction to select the credential since the credential name is known and static? I would want to look up the user-scoped credential by the hard-coded credential ID and use it automatically in the pipeline. This pipeline is only ever started by logged-in users who all have created a user credential (in global scope) with the same static name.

I'm using the latest Jenkins, currently set to "logged in users can do anything". The Authorize Project plugin is installed with "Run as user who triggered the build" strategy selected.

The following test was based on a suggestion [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020747/134536), but it does not find the secret "salainen" in my test environment.

```
script {
    withCredentials([[
        $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', 
        passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', 
        credentialsId: 'salainen'
    ]]) {
        echo "Username is $USERNAME"
        echo "Password is $PASSWORD"
    }
}
```

There seem to be several CloudBees tickets that relate to user-scoped credentials, many of which have been resolved, but it is not clear if the functionality I'm looking for has been implemented and/or if some workaround exists. For example:

- [User-scoped credentials cannot be looked up in pipeline](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38963) (resolved)
- [Cannot use user-scoped credentials from pipeline input step parameters](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47699) (resolved)
- [User Scoped credentials are not used by the "withCredentials" pipeline step](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44772) (open)

Thanks for any insights!